# Action Button goes to Overflow of the Action Bar

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar

My menu is defined as:

```
<menu 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.opendoors.registration.BusinessProfActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_done"
        android:title="@string/action_done"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_accept"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

Despite using `ifRoom` in `showAsAction`, my button still goes to the overflow menu.

I have also tried replacing:

> xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

with

> `xmlns:compat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

as well as

> app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
>   with
>   compat:showAsAction="ifRoom"

However, that doesn't work either, even though it was suggested in similar questions. What am I missing?

Maybe the following error might have something to do with this?

```
06-10 04:50:34.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1697): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
instantiate application android.app.Application: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable
to get package info for com.mypackage.app; is package not installed?
```

Comment: if you want to display it always then use app:showAsAction="always"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:`android:showAsAction="ifRoom"`

Comment: I downvoted by mistake, unfortunately it wouldn't let me change it to an upvote when I noticed that you were correct. However, if you edit your comment, I can change it to an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use always instead of ifRoom?

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_done"
    android:title="@string/action_done"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_accept"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the only item in the menu but perhaps you can try playing around with the ordering. android:orderInCategory="1"

Comment: I'll try that, but looking at this: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html gives me the impression that ordering should not matter.

Comment: No, but indicating "always" should also force the menu item to be shown.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html

Comment: It should... but for some reason it doesn't. Oh! Perhaps this error I'm getting in my logcat when I run the emulator might explain it? I'll edit my question with the error.

Comment: For some reason, I had to specify `android:showAsAction="always"` for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try: `app:showAsAction="always"`